# AutoMapper assigning the wrong value using UseValue

Tags: automapper

I have the following code snippet:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<WorkOrderServiceTypeViewModel, WorkOrderServiceType>()
    .ForMember(x => x.CompanyId, opt => opt.UseValue(_companyId));
Mapper.Map(model, workOrderServiceType);
```

When I run this, my watch shows that _companyId is 16, but after running the Mapper.Map, workOrderServiceType.CompanyId is 11.

Am I doing something wrong here?

ETA: It appears that the .UseValue only gets executed once.  Any ideas why?

[image]

For reference, here are my 2 models:

```
public class WorkOrderServiceTypeViewModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Residential { get; set; }
    public bool Commercial { get; set; }
    public bool Restoration { get; set; }
    public bool Cleaning { get; set; }
    public bool Storage { get; set; }
}
```

and the database model:

[image]

Comment: Try MapFrom instead of UseValue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4663048/3707342

Comment: I tried this with the same results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want runtime values to be used on a mapping, you need to use the runtime values support in AutoMapper:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<WorkOrderServiceTypeViewModel, WorkOrderServiceType>()
    .ForMember(x => x.CompanyId, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(res => res.Context.Options.Items["CompanyId"]));
```

Then in your mapping code:

```
Mapper.Map(model, workOrderServiceType, opt => opt.Items["CompanyId"] = _companyId);
```

Your configuration should be static and executed once - AutoMapper assumes this. So to pass runtime values into mapping, I expose a dictionary you can stuff any value in to be used inside your mapping configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Is _companyId a local private variable?  It doesn't look like it is a member of WorkOrderServiceTypeViewModel, which you are mapping from?  If so, why use AutoMapper at all and not just a straight assignment?  (Sorry if I am not understanding where _companyId is coming from)

Comment: _companyId is a variable that is passed into the constructor of the class.  Apparently, the AutoMapper UseValue will persist the first value that is sent, which is why this is happening.  Basically, for now, I've removed the .UseValue altogether and I'm just doing a straight C# assignment.